# 3D LiDAR Data Inconsistency and Costmap Performance Optimization

Tags: ros2, lidar, laser, 2dcostmap

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently engaged in a project utilizing a non-repetitive 3D LiDAR system, characterized by a Vertical Field of View (VFOV) of 52° to -7° and a Horizontal Field of View (HFOV) of 360°. The system operates at a data publishing rate of 6-7 Hz. Its scanning is something like this:

[image: Lidar scanning]

I have observed a level of inconsistency in the point cloud data with each scan, resulting in a variable data density at different points in the 3D space. I am employing the spatio-temporal voxel layer for marking obstacles in the cost map. However, a noticeable flickering effect is present in the global costmap, an issue that exacerbates with increased distance, likely due to reduced data availability for obstacle marking.

[image: S6x2G.gif]

An illustrative example of this issue is provided in the attached image for your reference. While I have managed to mitigate the flickering effect by extending the decay time, I am uncertain if this is the optimal solution. This adjustment impacts the clearing performance, and it is highly desirable to swiftly eliminate the previous poses of mobile obstacles to maintain the integrity and accuracy of the data.

[image: S6x2B.gif]

I am reaching out to inquire if you have encountered similar challenges with this type of 3D LiDAR, and if so, I would greatly appreciate your insights and recommendations for enhancing the costmap performance, maybe exploring alternative parameter tuning for the voxel layer plugin to address this issue. For your convenience, I have attached the parameters currently in use.

```
stvl:
plugin: "spatio_temporal_voxel_layer/SpatioTemporalVoxelLayer"
enabled:               true
voxel_decay:           1.5  
decay_model:           0     
voxel_size:            0.05   
track_unknown_space:   false   
mark_threshold:        4     
origin_z:              0.0   
publish_voxel_map:     true   
transform_tolerance:   0.3    # seconds
mapping_mode:          false  
observation_sources:   lidar_clear lidar_mark
lidar_mark:
enabled: true                
data_type: PointCloud2
topic: /lidar/points
marking: true
clearing: false
obstacle_range: 10.0          
min_obstacle_height: 0.07   
max_obstacle_height: 1.4    
expected_update_rate: 0.0   
observation_persistence: 0.0
inf_is_valid: false          
filter: "passthrough" 
voxel_min_points: 0         
clear_after_reading: false   
vertical_fov_angle: 0.923  # 52°
vertical_fov_padding: 0.0    
horizontal_fov_angle: 6.29  
lidar_clear:
enabled: true               
data_type: PointCloud2
topic: /lidar/points
marking: false
clearing: true
max_obstacle_height: 3.0
min_obstacle_height: -3.0
obstacle_range: 10.0          
min_z: 0.0                 
max_z: 20.0                 
vertical_fov_angle: 0.923  
vertical_fov_padding: 0.0  
horizontal_fov_angle: 6.29  
clear_after_reading: false  
decay_acceleration: 20.0  
filter: "voxel"   
voxel_min_points: 3         
model_type: 1
```